# Trouble retaining vertical scroll position when swapping images

Tags: jquery

I've been at this for a while, can't seem to get scrollTop to work, not sure what I'm doing wrong. Here is the site I'm working on: http://graysonearle.com/newtest/#prettyPhoto/6/ basically you can scroll the stuff on the left, select a thumbnail, then it loads in the content portion. The problem is it resets the vertical scroll position which is less than ideal. What do I do?

Still can't figure it out. I imagine that it's because the content is faded out, and doesn't exist, so that vertical scroll location is no good anymore, as it needs to reset to the top, to an area that exists. Can I put some sort of place holder there or something?

Comment: must be browser dependent, I can't see any scroll change

Comment: Thanks for checking! What browser you rockin, friend?

Comment: I see intermittent abnormalities. In Firefox, sometimes the thumbnails has a horizontal scrollbar just for that region. In Chrome, the About text/inner-scroll section appears under the thumbnails. I think these issues can cause scrollTop to work incorrectly.